# How to edit a venue using the Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

i'm using the Foursquare API in a project in order to manage venues informations through my app. Everything works fine, until I try to POST data to edit a venue details.

Actually, the post request seems to work fine, since a I get a 200 status code response. However I never see my changes on the platform. Here's the response I get :

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "requestId": "5d0a1b210d2be70039f03fc4"
    },
    "notifications": [
        {
            "type": "notificationTray",
            "item": {
                "unreadCount": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "response": {
        "woes": []
    }
}
```

Did any one succesfully used Foursquare API to edit venue details and then saw the changes on the platform ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Which API do you use? If you use https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/proposededit, your proposal need to be approved by Super User community.

Comment: ok thanks for you answer @KosukeOgawa. Indeed I use the endpoint 'proposeedit'. Is there an other API where I don't need approval ?

Comment: As far as I know, that kind of API doesn't exist.

Comment: @WT_11 , did you found any solutions for this?